# Por que é que 'ç' é convertido para %C3%A7 URL, e não %E7?

Tags: url

Quando fui codificar o caractere 'ç' para o formato da query (onde ficam os parâmetros) do URL, obtive:

> %C3%A7

`%` especifica um byte hexadecimal, mas por que quase todos caracteres (incluindo 'ç') devem ser especificados por 2 bytes hexadecimais?

E como `%C3%A7` poderia representar o caractere 'ç'? 'ç' não poderia ser especificado com apenas esse byte `%E7` (231)?

Para clarificar: a intenção é saber como o caractere 'ç' é codificado, como ele se torna `%C3%A7`.

Comment: Uma lidinha aqui pode ajudar: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8 - Em especial a parte que explica a quantidade variável de bytes por caractere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O [RFC 3986](http://www.gbiv.com/protocols/uri/rfc/rfc3986.html) não especifica qual codificação deve ser usada para caracteres non-ASCII.

A codificação de URL envolve um par de hexadecimais, o que equivale a 8 bits.
Seria possível representar os caracteres non-ASCII todos dentro desse contexto. No entanto, o que tornou inviável é que muitos idiomas possui seu próprio padrão para representar os seus respectivos caracteres em 8-bit. Além do mais, em idiomas como o chinês, muitos caracteres não cabem em 8-bits.

Por isso adotada a especificação [RFC 3629](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629), a qual propôs padronizar os caracteres non-ASCII com a codificação UTF-8.

É importante entender que dentro do grupo non-ASCII existem os caracteres reservados e não reservados.

Na tabela dos caracteres não reservados, temos

```
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 - _ .~
```

Esses são os reservados:

```
! * ' ( ) ; : @ & = + $ , / ? % # [ ]
```

Note que `~` não é reservado, no entanto, ele pode ser codificado. Porém, a recomendação é que **não** o codifique.

O que acontece no exemplo que postou do cedilha **ç**?

Obviamente, como o `ç` não é ASCII, é tratado como UTF8 conforme a recomendação `RFC 3629`, acima mencionado.

Isso em si já explica o motivo de estar codificado em UTF-8, representando 2 pares hexadecimais.

O "ç" é codificado em UTF-8 com 2 bytes `C3` (hex) e `A7` (hex), sendo representados nesse formato "%c3" e "%a7" respectivamente. O escopo %HH%HH. O par `A7` é o que identifica como UTF-8.

Os browsers apenas imprimem a forma decodificada. E muitos protocolos transmitem  UTF-8 sem precisar formatar para o escopo %HH, seja de 1 ou 2 pares.

<sup>*byte != bit</sup>

<sup>*url encoded != html entities</sup>

Por curiosidade, os browsers suportam na URL os caracteres multibyte há alguns anos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4):

Esta string %C3%A7 é a codificação UTF-8 do caracter 'ç' para uso em URLs.

Referência:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Outra página interessante:
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00e7/index.htm

Ferramentas online:
http://www.url-encode-decode.com/
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Definição oficial.
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629

Transformação de E7 em C3A7

```
E7: 11 100111
    ^^ ^^^^^^

110x xxxx | 10xx xxxx
1100 0011 | 1010 0111 --> C3A7
       ^^     ^^ ^^^^
```

Comment: As referências ainda não respondem à pergunta, agora atualizei a pergunta para forçar a diferença entre a codificação do UTF-8 e a codificação dos URLs.

Comment: E7 é o codepoint Unicode do caracter 'ç'. A codificação UTF-16 é 00E7. A codificação UTF-8 é C3A7.

Comment: Infelizmente ainda não consegui entender como o UTF-8 faz com que 'ç' se torne C3A7, não há explicação. Novamente, como C3-A7 pode representar o caractere 'ç' se seu código é 0xe7?